# Proving $a^2+b^2>0$ without cases, set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that $a^2+b^2>0$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$, along with the equality case $(0,0)$, however, the only proof I can think of is a very brute-force case-bashing method, considering every case where $a>0,\ a<0$ etc. Is there a way to prove this using set theory/order axioms?

Comment: You might want to say more about what axioms and theorems you are working with. There are a lot of ways to formulate order axioms and a lot of different starting points for a proof like this.

Comment: I should add that, because of the way ordered fields are axiomatized, it's almost impossible to avoid breaking into cases for these sorts of elementary proofs at some stage. This is a consequence of the trichotomy axiom: a number is either $0$, positive, or negative. That said, you can save yourself a lot of work by proving lemmas and theorems. For example, if you already have that $a^2 \geq 0$ for all $a$, then you can make pretty quick work of this proof.

Comment: I'm working with the axioms that determine what makes a field vs. an ordered field. We've been recently proving the existence of subtraction, division, etc. so I'm not entirely sure how much I can leave to assumption in the proof.

Comment: Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field). Do any of these axiomatizations look familiar? Are you by any chance using Spivak's book?

Comment: Yes, those are the axioms we are using. We're using Apostol, specifically the introductory chapter. I believe this exercise appears in the text among the set theory relations and order axioms.

Comment: The first set of axioms, yes?

Comment: Well, all of them.

Comment: See if the proof I've laid out makes sense. If it doesn't use the axiomatic framework you're working with, I leave translation to you as an exercise.

Comment: I believe it does -- thank you very much :)). I'll give it the check as soon as I've thoroughly understood it. I'm a little confused on 4, specifically how 3 implies that $a^2=0$ if $a\leq 0$.

Comment: Just kidding I get it :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we know that $a > b$ implies $a + c > b + c$ for all $a,b,c$ and that $a > 0$, $b > 0$ implies $ab > 0$. We'll prove the result in steps. I'm going to assume you've already proved all the basic facts that follow from the field axioms, e.g. $0a = 0$, $-a = (-1)a$, $(-1)^2 = 1$, and so on.

1. If $a \geq 0$, then $-a \leq 0$. Suppose $a \geq 0$. Then, by the order axioms, $0 = -a + a \geq -a + 0 = -a$, i.e. $-a \leq 0$.
2. If $a \leq 0$, then $-a \geq 0$. This follows by an argument identical to 1.
3. If $a \leq 0$ and $b \leq 0$, then $ab \geq 0$. By 2, $-a \geq 0$ and $-b \geq 0$. Thus $(-a)(-b) \geq 0$. Hence $((-1)a)((-1)b) \geq 0$, so $(-1)^2 ab \geq 0$, whence we conclude $ab = (1)ab \geq 0$.
4. $a^2 \geq 0$ for all $a$. If $a \leq 0$, then, by 3, $a^2 \geq 0$. If $a \geq 0$, then, by the order axioms, $a^2 \geq 0$.
5. $a^2 + b^2 \geq 0$ for all $a,b$. By 4, we have $a^2 \geq 0$ and $b^2 \geq 0$. By the order axioms $a^2 + b^2 \geq 0 + b^2 = b^2 \geq 0$.
6. $0^2 + 0^2 = 0$. This follows from the field axioms.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... $a^2 \geq 0$ (and $= 0$ if and only if $a=0$) for $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Likewise for $b$.

QED.

By the way:  What does set theory or order axioms have to do with any of this?

Comment: We've just been recently proving the existence of division, addition, subtraction etc. from the axioms that determine what makes a field or an ordered field and I'm not sure if I can leave $a^2\geq 0$ to assumption

Comment: What do you mean by "Proving $a^2 + b^2 \geq 0$ without cases, set theory" and "Is there a way to prove this using set theory/order axioms?"  These two sentences seem contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know already that $a^2\ge 0$ with equality only if $a=0$, you can do:

Suppose $b\neq 0$, then $b^2\gt 0$ and $a^2\ge 0\gt -b^2$ whence $a^2+b^2\ge b^2\gt0$. (you can add the term $b^2$ to each component, because adding the same thing doesn't change the order)

If $b=0$ then $a^2+b^2=a^2\ge0$ with equality only if $a=0$.